# create draggable div on click make the parrent draggable not the new div

Tags: javascript, onclick, draggable

I create a div on click of the 4 item in the second row.
I would like to create a new draggable div like the first one.
I'm sure it's the .draggable() that cause the problem.

I try many other place but can't figure out where to add the .draggable()

```
    var i = 0;
 $('#dropbtn').click(function() {
    // insert a SPAN tag with class="spn" at the end in all DIVs with class="cls"
     if(i == 0){
         $('#dropbtn').append('<div class="boxArt red" row="2" col="4" id="dragme3">DRAG ME3</div>').draggable();
         i=i+1;    
     }
});
```

[JSFIFFLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieubujold/vEftN/)

Comment: Your jsFiddle seems to be working for me. What browser are you using? Or maybe I am reading your question incorrectly. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the `.draggable()` at the wrong element. The `.append()` method returns the container element, not what you added.

This should work:

```
$('<div class="boxArt red" row="2" col="4" id="dragme3">DRAG ME3</div>').draggable().appendTo('#dropbtn');
```